# invalid syntax (views.py, line 34)

Tags: django

I'm new to django, I'm getting an invalid syntax error in views.py file. Is there a way i can debug syntax errors in django? When running the development server with python manage.py runserver I'm getting the below error

```
===============
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (views.py, line 34)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (views.py, line 34)
Exception Location: /home/arajguru/training/mycode/myshop/orders/urls.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  /home/arajguru/training/mycode/env/myshop/bin/python
```

.......
    ===============

```
Below is my views.py file:


from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart
#from .tasks import order_created
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                        product=item['product'],
                                        price=item['price'],
                                        quantity=item['quantity'])  
            # clear the cart
            cart.clear()
                       # launch asynchronous task
#            order_created.delay(order.id)
            # set the order in the session
            request.session['order_id'] = order.id
            # redirect to the payment
        return redirect(reverse('payment:process'))

    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request,`enter code here`
                  'orders/order/create.html',
                  {'cart': cart, 'form': form}
```

Comment: line 34 doesn't mean a lot to anyone other than yourself, please try to create a [mcve] when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't close the `render` function with parenthesis.

P.S. Use Pycharm to avoid syntax errors. It will show you immediately if something is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Close the render function parenthesis.
add backslash after "enter code here`\"